# Performance: need to loop through formula row-by-row and change to values

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, optimization

I am looking for a solution to improve the following code..
The original problem is, that I have a lot of rows with complicated formulas. This creates a lot of loading times.

So my solution: calculate row by row after data load and replace formula with the value.
Unfortunatly this loads very long as well, because of the flush()...

Do you have any suggestions how I could improve the performance?
Many thanks!!

```
var copyrange = SpreadsheetApp
               .getActive()
               .getSheetByName("Data")
               .getRange("AZ2:CP2");
               
var lastrow = datasheet.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 1; i < lastrow; i++) {
    copyrange.copyTo(copyrange.offset(i,0));
    SpreadsheetApp.flush()
    copyrange.offset(i,0).copyTo(copyrange.offset(i,0), {contentsOnly:true}); 
  }
```

Comment: Well, remove the flush? Also [edit] to explain what the code does.

Comment: Although not obvious from your script, I believe what is happening is you copy range AZ2:CP2 to the next row.  This range contains formulas that are dependant on the preceeding columns.  For example the copied forumulas in AZ3:CP3 are dependant on lets sya A3, since copyTo updated the formula references to that row.  What may be causing your performance issue is repeated copyTo, each a server request.  Why not copy all the formulas, let it recalculate, then replace AZ3 and beyond with the values.

Comment: This looks to be a X-Y problem... instead of using formulas to do the calculations use JavaScript and add all of the results at once instead of using a loop.

Comment: I agree what @Rubén has mentioned. What prevents you from doing the calculation in javascript? Show a sample sheet and the expected outcome. If you are just going to get the value, why not do the calculations in javascript instead and write it in bulk.